# Redis: using ZRANGE to search for a single value?

Tags: redis, floating-point-comparison

If in a Redis database a sorted set is filled with decimal values, how can I search in it for an exact value given as a decimal value, under the condition that exactly *this* decimal value was also used when filling the sorted set?

Since Redis does the conversion to binary for us, wouldn't the rounding error when using `ZADD` be just exactly the same as when using `ZSCORE`? So if e.g. a key was added with score 0.1, can I retrieve it by using `ZRANGE <sortedset> 0.1 0.1`?

In other words, I'm looking for the minimal Δ that I should use for this special case of float comparison in `ZRANGE <sortedset> <value>-Δ <value>+Δ`. In my opinion, Δ = 0 should work.

Of course, I might get other keys with associated decimal values that weren't originally used when filling but that is unavoidable. Their number should be just as low as possible.